# ng serve shows blank page when using nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am working on an Angular 7 project. I have started ng serve and it is serving on http://localhost:4200.  tag is set as .

I have configured nginx as reverse proxy as shown below:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost` I get a blank page and following messages in console:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/runtime.js”
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/polyfills.js”
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/styles.js”
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/vendor.js”
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/main.js”.
```

Application is working as expected when I navigate to `http://localhost:4200`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This might give you answer:
[Traefik Path to an Angular app running in docker with nginx won't work using the root path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54084465/traefik-path-to-an-angular-app-running-in-docker-with-nginx-wont-work-using-the)